# ApiPlatform - implement security authorization on subresource route

Tags: symfony, security, api-platform.com, subresource-integrity, symfony4-voter

I'm using `Symfony5` and `ApiPlatform`

I have a `User` entity and a `Product` entity.

I want to list all my user's products through a subressource, to do so I've implemented my `user` class as follow :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read", "user:list"}},
 *          "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"user:put", "user:post"}}
 *     },
 *    subresourceOperations={
 *         "api_users_consultations_get_subresource"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *         }
 *    },
 *    collectionOperations={
 *        "get"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:list"}}
 *          },
 *        "post"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "security_post_denormalize"="is_granted('POST', object)",
 *              "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"user:post"}}
 *        }
 *    },
 *    itemOperations={
 *        "get"={
 *          "method"="GET",
 *          "security"="is_granted('GET', object)",
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read"}}
 *         }
 *    }
 * )
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false, hardDelete=false)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:list"})
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="user")
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
    private $product;
}
```

It does create a route `/users/{id}/products` and return me what I want.

The part where I'm blocking is when I want to add authorization to this route:

- `ROLE_ADMIN` can access this route
- `ROLE_USER` who own the ressource can access it
- All the other roles will receive `FORBIDDEN`

To do so I've followed the doc : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/#using-serialization-groups

- Added `subresourceOperations` to `@ApiSubresource` annotation
- recovered the name of my grenerated route `api_users_consultations_get_subresource` through the `bin/console debug:router` command
- and simply set a `security=is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')` method like for other operations.
- or `security=is_granted('SUB_LIST', object)` to hit the `voter`

but when I run my tests I get `200` where I should receive `403`, the `UserVoter` or `ProductVoter` are not triggered nor the `is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')` rule.

As if the `subresourceOperations` annotation wasn't recognize by the `ApiPlatform`.

I've also tried changing the name of the operation from `api_users_consultations_get_subresource` to :

- `consultations_get_subresource`
- `api_consultations_get_subresource`
- `clients_get_subresource`
- `api_clients_get_subresource`

and different other variants as I saw on `Github` it solved the issue in some cases (like here https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1581#issuecomment-662503549) but it has not worked for me.

So I'm wondering is there something I havn't done to implement it correctly ?

Is it a known issue of `ApiPlatform` ?

Does anyone see where my logic is failing ?

Is there another way to setup security on `subresource` routes ?

Are there more docs on security realted to `subresource`? I have not find a lot of material on this particular subject

Comment: Hello, when you are loading collection I think that voter will not help you, BUT can you take a look for this query extension https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension
Can you tell me if helps you?

Best

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Yeah that would work, the only thing that disturb me about it is that it would be implementing multiple 'security' rules outside of the `voter` as we have multiple `subresource` and spread the security logic in multiple places of the app. Might also decide to use `filters` instead of subresource, so the security logic stay in the voter `LIST` attribute. I'm gonna keep digging on `subresource` security even though it seems it's a general `ApiPlatform` issue

Comment: I've ended up using your solution. Implementing `Doctrine extension` as you recommended to avoid even having to use `ApiSubresource`, it's way simplier. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, enjoy it